# SQLException (ORA-00900) with Java to PL SQL Date

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have given a PL/SQL function with the following parameters:

```
FUNCTION "insert_foo"(c_i IN VARCHAR2, c_t IN VARCHAR2,
         c_d IN VARCHAR2, c_x IN NUMBER, c_b IN NUMBER,
         c_e IN NUMBER, c_valid IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS
```

Now I am trying to call this function from a Java program, but I am getting the Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900
```

I am sure, that the last parameter, the date, is the reason for this exception..

I am using it this way:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);    
// this is my parameter for the Callable Statement
new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Can you help me?!

Kind regards and thanks!

Comment: [ORA-00900](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00900_invalid_sql_statement.htm): ***The statement is not recognized as a valid SQL statement.*** *This error can occur if the Procedural Option is not installed and a SQL statement is issued that requires this option* ***(for example, a CREATE PROCEDURE statement)***. *[...]*
***Action: Correct the syntax or install the Procedural Option.***

Comment: What makes you sure that the date is the problem?

Comment: Show us the SQL code that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem!

It wasn't the date, as I supposed. I just didn't call the pl/sql function in the right way.

To call a PL/SQL function like

```
FUNCTION "insert_foo"(c_i IN VARCHAR2, c_t IN VARCHAR2,
     c_d IN VARCHAR2, c_x IN NUMBER, c_b IN NUMBER,
     c_e IN NUMBER, c_valid IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS
```

you have to use a Query-String like

```
"{? = call insert_foo(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
```

First, create a CallableStatement (with an instance of your java.sql.Connection9, then fill the "?"s with values an then, execute the function:

```
CallableStatement test = java.sql.Connection
        .prepareCall(
    "{? = call insert_foo(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

test.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER); // <- OutParameter (!)
test.setString(2, "TEST");
test.setString(3, "TEST");
test.setString(4, "TEST");
test.setInt(5, 12);
test.setInt(6, 13);
test.setInt(7, 123);
test.setDate(8, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));

System.out.println("-+-+- RESULT -+-+-> " + test.executeUpdate());
```

Hint:

If you write "CALL" instead of "call" in the query

```
"{? = call insert_foo(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
```

you get an SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL92-Zeichenfolge in falschem Format in Position: 5. Expecting "call"
```

Comment: the created SQL statement looks like: "{'<OUT>' = call ERUL.insert_exactrule('TEST','TEST','TEST',12,13,123,to_date('02/11/2015 
00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))}"